# How to delete SU binaries without root?

Tags: rooting, adb, samsung

My Android device used to be properly rooted, I had root access to things, but the root manager (old version of vRoot, no computer) was a virus. So, I deleted the root program and I was gonna root another way, but I can't delete the old su binaries. I was gonna try and use something like Odin and TWRP to root, or perhaps another method. I have a **Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7' Wifi Only (SM-T210)**.

How do I delete the SU binaries without root? Maybe using adb? I do not have fastboot.

Comment: are you open to flash custom recovery ? also try to install SuperSU from the play store open it if it ask to update su binary say yes and choose normal method ,see if that updates you su binary or not

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I can't. I tried to update the su binaries through supersu and it said that it failed. Also, I tried to flash TWRP through Odin, but it didn't work.

Comment: it didn't flash the TWRP ? you have truble flashing TWRP or you did flash but you din't figure a way to use it to remove the SU binary ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf It didn't flash the TWRP. I booted into recovery (with ADB) and it was my usual device recovery. That is meant to root the device by installing the SU binaries but I had the 2 problems. 1. TWRP didn't flash and 2. I still had the old SU binaries. Should I flash the stock firmware? Or will that still keep the bin and xbin folders from /system

Comment: so you wanna delete the su binary so you can root again ? your problem is how to regain root access right ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf Yes and yes.

Comment: did you try flashing this zip file threw recovery ? https://download.chainfire.eu/696/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip

Comment: You don't need to delete the existing binaries.  If you root it properly they'll be overwritten.